# How do I block updating a specific device with fwupd?

Tags: firmware, software-updates

I want to be able to block updating my system's firmware with fwupd as later BIOS versions block the ability to undervolt the CPU (yes I'm aware this leaves my system susceptible to plundervolt and later security vulnerabilities).

I am running KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 20.04 (where the `fwupdmgr` version is 1.7.5) and typically update via Discover. Previously I just disabled the LVFS remote in Discover but this has the unintended consequences of blocking all updates (including for other devices) from the LVFS.

Looking at the output of `fwupdmgr --help`, I can see there is a `block-firmware [CHECKSUM]` subcommand but, as far as I can see, this only blocks specific firmware versions from being installed whereas I want to block *any* updates to the 'System Firmware' device. Is this possible?

Comment: Similar problem, where I'll have an external devices that has issues after a certain firmware version. Would like to prevent the update from showing up too.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/128292

Comment: I don't think that's relevant as fwupd is separate from the normal Ubuntu package manager (dpkg/apt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on fwupdmgr 1.8.1. This works for me: check the 'GUIDs' listed in the 'System Firmware' section:

```
$ fwupdmgr get-updates
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • SSD 970 EVO 2TB
 • UEFI dbx
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Package level of Dell dock
 • RTS5413 in Dell dock
 • RTS5487 in Dell dock
 • VMM5331 in Dell dock
 • WD19
 • KXG60ZNV256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB
Precision 7730
│
└─System Firmware:
  │   Device ID:          deadbeefc0e948deadbeef16a5f703f3deadbeef
  │   Summary:            UEFI ESRT device
  │   Current version:    1.10.1
  │   Minimum Version:    1.10.1
  │   Vendor:             Dell (DMI:Dell Inc.)
  │   Update State:       Success
  │   GUIDs:              db72c932-b3c6-beef-b382-3fdeadbeef7b
  │                       230c8b18-dead-53ec-838b-6deadbeef93a ← main-system-firmware
  │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
```

In the `/etc/fwupd/daemon.conf` file, add them to the `DisabledDevices` var:

```
--- /etc/fwupd/daemon.conf.bak  2022-06-17 11:03:12.910125870 +0200
+++ /etc/fwupd/daemon.conf      2022-06-17 11:13:42.965451740 +0200
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 
 # Allow blocking specific devices by their GUID
 # Uses semicolons as delimiter
-DisabledDevices=
+DisabledDevices=db72c932-b3c6-4640-b382-3f4619ab447b;230c8b18-dead-53ec-838b-6deadbeef93a
 
 # Allow blocking specific plugins
 # Uses semicolons as delimiter
```

(One of them may be enough, didn't test)

Restart fwupd and refresh:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart fwupd

$ fwupdmgr refresh --force
Updating lvfs
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Successfully downloaded new metadata: 6 local devices supported
```

I used to see 7 supported devices in there.

Verify:

```
$ fwupdmgr get-updates
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • SSD 970 EVO 2TB
 • UEFI dbx
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Package level of Dell dock
 • RTS5413 in Dell dock
 • RTS5487 in Dell dock
 • VMM5331 in Dell dock
 • WD19
 • KXG60ZNV256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB
No updates available
```

Yay!

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly for me with v1.7.5 as well (once I stopped being an idiot and realised that a semicolon is `;` and not `:` or `,`).